# Give a serious explanation of the difference between an equation and a function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definition, foundations

What's the difference between an equation and a function? I mean, I am not seeking for a high school-like answer like "an equation has an equals sign". I want to know what is the fundamental difference between the two. Why we need these two concepts, that seems to me to be the same thing? In physics we heard a lot about equations, but if we call all them functions, wouldn't we be right?

Comment: An equation has a number of solutions (between $0$ and $\infty$). A function maps each value in a given domain to a value in a given range. I'm kind of asking myself what's the non-difference between an equation and a function, because there doesn't seem to be anything in common between them. It's like asking about the difference between a cat and a table.

Comment: A function is a rule that assigns an object (output) to an object (input).  An equation is a statement the expresses the equality of two expressions.

Comment: @barakmanos +1 for the "cat and a table" comment hahaha

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow: Thanks, but I'm starting to think that it might sound a little disrespecting in a way. To OP - no disrespect meant, there's just very little room for comparison.

Comment: @barakmanos I just think it highlights the main problem in a rather amusing way--perhaps OP could be more clear about what is tripping him/her up.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow: Yep, I agree. "not seeking for a high school-like answer" doesn't quite contribute to understanding what kind of answer he or she are expecting.

Answer (score 3):

A function is something that yields a well-defined output for any appropriate input. Some, but not all, functions can be represented by equations, and not every equation naturally represents a function. In order to see an equation as a function, you have to decide what the output (the dependent variable) is supposed to be, and then you have to determine whether that has a unique value, given inputs that fill in the rest of the blanks in the equation.

Consider the equation $w=z^2$. We could interpret this equation as giving us a formula for $w$, as a function of $z$, because for a given $z$ value, we can say exactly what $w$ must be.

On the other hand, that same equation doesn't give us a formula for $z$ as a function of $w$. That's because, using the value $w=1$, it's impossible to say whether our output should be $z=1$ or $z=-1$.

I hope that this answer addresses your question appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

They *are* the same in a sense. A function *is* technically an "equation", but an equation is not necessarily a function. It is incontrovertibly true; however, to say that any two values separated by an equals sign is considered an equation.  $5=2+3$ is an equation, but not a function. $y=2x+3$ or equivalently, $f(x)=2x+3$ is a function, but also an equation because it involves an equals sign.  **Functions *are* equations that have both constants and variables which arrange in some way to map the function's value about those variables' dimensions.**

Comment: 5 = 2 + 3 is an equality. An equation must contain at least one variable.

Comment: I think maybe it's the opposite: every equation is a function but not every function is an equation (some functions don't have a clear set of calculations to perform it).

Answer (score 2):

In many cases, the distinction is subtle. A function is formally defined as a mapping between two sets $X$ and $Y$ in which each element of $X$ is assigned (that is, maps to) an element in $Y$. An equation is a statement about the equivalent value of two expressions. In this sense, a function $f$ is an equation because the symbol $f(x)$ is equivalent to some expression, probably involving $x$. A subtlety is that while we often express a function as $f(x)=...$, this is an equation while the function is more properly denoted $f$ (without reference of $x$). An example (from physics, for your sake) which would not (I think) be appropriately called a function is $$\nabla\cdot E=\frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}.$$ This is one of Maxwell's equations which is certainly not (as written) a mapping between sets.

Comment: Saying that a function is defined as $f(x)=x^2+5$ is really a high school answer. An equation is really just part of a function definition. For example 
$$f:D\rightarrow R:\text{such that for every } x\in D \text{ there exists } f(x)\in R\text{ such that } f(x)=x^2+5$$
Unfortunately though, when pressed, a high school teacher will usually just say that "$x$ is just a *dummy* variable".

+1 Thank you for pointing out that the function is properly referred to just as $f$, instead of $f(x)$.

Comment: Yes. But I  preferr "there exists an y such that y = x^2 + 5".